# Sum values of a specific property in javascript object

Tags: javascript, foreach

On a click event in my application I am returned `highlights` - an array of features (each time of differing length). So `console.log(highlights)` produces:

[image]

My objective is to return the sum of the values contained in `properties.census2010_Pop2010` for each feature in the object.  So far I have tried the code below but nothing is returned in the console.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
total = Object.create(null);

highlights.feature.properties.forEach(function (a) {
    a.census2010_Pop2010.forEach(function (b) {
        total = total + b.census2010_Pop2010;
    });
});

console.log(total);
```

Comment: Why do you initialise `total` as an object? Don't you want it to be a number?

Comment: You are saying that properties is an array.... it is an object.... You should be doing forEach over the array....

Comment: Total should be a number, yes

Comment: I would recommend using the array method reduce.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here. Your description doesn't match the picture of your source structure. You've said you're trying to sum `census2010_Pop2010` "for each feature in the object", but each `Feature` in the object only has a single `properties.census2010_Pop2010` entry, so "summing" doesn't come into it...?

Comment: are you sure you're not getting error when executing that code ? you can't use forEach on object

Comment: The object contains an array of 23 features - each feature contains a property `census2010_Pop2010`.  I am trying to get the sum of those 23 values

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`highlights` is an array and you should be looping over that.

```js
var highlights = [
  {properties : { census2010_Pop2010: 10}},
  {properties : { census2010_Pop2010: 20}},
  {properties : { census2010_Pop2010: 30}}
]

var total = highlights.reduce( function(tot, record) {
    return tot + record.properties.census2010_Pop2010;
},0);


console.log(total);
```

If you want to use forEach it would be like this:

```js
var highlights = [
  {properties : { census2010_Pop2010: 10}},
  {properties : { census2010_Pop2010: 20}},
  {properties : { census2010_Pop2010: 30}}
]

var total = 0;
highlights.forEach( function(record) {
    total += record.properties.census2010_Pop2010;
});


console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved by using `reduce` to total the value of `census2010_Pop2010`:

```
const total = highlights.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val.properties.census2010_Pop2010, 0);
```

*Note: I have used the [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
 to keep it concise, this is not necessary but, becoming more common when adopting a more functional style with methods like `map`, `filter` and `reduce`.*

Answer (score 2):

```
total = 0;

highlights.forEach(function(a) {
    total += Number(a.Feature.properties.census2010_Pop2010);
})
console.log(total);
```

You need to loop through each of the "Feature" objects in the "highlights" array.  You start with a total of 0, then incrementally add the census2010_Pop2010 values from each Feature.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks milo526.  I've updated my answer to include an explanation